# How do I go from 1 copper propane line to 5 propane lines? Do they make a splitter like cable tv does?

Tags: propane

Do they make a copper propane line splitter like cable tv. I nee to go from 1 line to 5

Comment: The search term you're looking for is "propane manifold". Google that.

Answer (score 2):

Simply put Four Tees in a line, or two Crosses. 1 in, 4 side outs, one end out.

[image: A cross] [image: A tee]

Of course, if you are adding 4 appliances to an existing installation, you might need to upgrade the line from the tank (sized for one appliance) to maintain adequate flow.

Likewise, be careful, or consider the possibility that a propane leak is potentially dangerous, and you may not be the best choice of person to "split" your propane line if you equate it to cable TV (i.e. have zero plumbing experience.)

Comment: +1 for calling out the significant difference between a plumbing manifold and an electronic RF signal splitter.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of compression fittings I would use flare fittings, with the copper flared by a very good "roller type " flaring tool (my choice). And by all means pressure test the lines before use.